# Passing NSString between ViewControllers

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, nsstring, segue

I need to pass a variable (`databasePath` - which is an `NSString`) between two view controllers.
In the from controller I have coded:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var thirdVC: ThirdViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ThirdViewController

    thirdVC.databasePath = databasePath
}
```

How do I define the variable, or write the receiving statement in the receiving controller?

I always get `nil`.

In the from ViewController the databasePath is declared here.  This creates me an SQL database that I can use to store information that the user enters.

```
    let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,
        .UserDomainMask, true)

    let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as String

    databasePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("contacts.db")
```

`databasePath` carries the relevant information to find where the database is stored.

On the ThirdViewController I have it set up so that you can view what is stored in the database.
There are no errors on the code.
I used `println("\(databasePath)")` to find there is no value to this on the ThirdViewController.

How do I define the variable, or write the receiving statement in the receiving controller in order for it to keep it's value?

Comment: Where is the databasePath variable being maintained in the source VC? Have you declared databasePath as a property in the destination VC?

Comment: Yeah, what is `databasePath` at this point in time? If you set a breakpoint, or print `databasePath` is it correct? The code you've written looks like it should work, but without the bigger picture we can't be sure.

Comment: I will edit the question to try and answer your question.

Comment: I hope that my edits help you understand the problem I have.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question what I understand is that you want to pass 'databasePath' NSString to "thirdVC: ThirdViewController", and how you can declare this variable in 'ThirdViewController' to access its passed value,

then you are doing just fine only you have to declare same name variable i.e  databasePath with its datatype i.e NSString and use it whereever you need its value, just make sure that 'ThirdViewController' is called after the view controller, that is passing the value.

Note: ThirdViewController should be the child class of the viewcontroller class which is passing the value.

I hope you got your answer :)